# Liferay 6 persistent sessions with very large table

Tags: java, session, tomcat, cluster-computing, liferay-6

I've implemented a liferay 6.2 cluster (with tomcat 7.x) and configured persistent sessions within tomcat configuration.
Everything is working fine, but i've notice that the table containing the sessions is very large.
Almost 46gb of space for ~2000 persisted sessions.
Is there any way to reduce the space of the data saved into session? 
I see there is a liferay property:

```
session.shared.attributes=COMPANY_,LIFERAY_SHARED_,org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE,PORTLET_RENDER_PARAMETERS_,PUBLIC_RENDER_PARAMETERS_POOL_,USER_
```

but i don't know if is relevant or not

Answer (score 0):

As Liferay says, session replication is not recommended.

https://web.liferay.com/es/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Clustering

```
Install an http load balancer and make sure your load balancer is set to sticky session mode. It is not recommended to use session replication for clustering.
```

Why? because it is not a scalable system. In 99% cases, you can use a load balancer with session affinity. BUT this is not the best way to scale a cluster, but it is better.

The best way would be implement session managament with JWT (json web token) or a similar mechanism, without java session, since every node doesn't know anything about sessions and it is the only way to scale linearly.